# React Native problemas con props y Stack.Navigator

Tags: react-native, screen, props

Tengo problemas en enviar datos a una función que esta en otra pantalla:

El código es el siguiente:

**Archivo App.js**
name es el parametro que deseo enviar

```
import React from 'react';
import Drawer from './scr/drawer1';

export default function App() {
 
  return (

    <Drawer name="MI_NOMBRE" appe="2"/
```

//name es el parametro que deseo enviar

```
  );
}
```

**Archivo drawer1.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function CompleScreen(route) {
  const { user } = route.params;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>"Esto CompleScreem con name: {JSON.stringify(user)}</Text>  
      </View>
      )
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function Drawer(props) {

    return (
```

//Hasta aquí llega props.name pero no lo puedo envíar a la funcion CompleScreen

```
      <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator>
         <Stack.Screen name="Completorio" component={CompleScreen} params= { user: 'props.name' } /
       </Stack.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer> 
   )
}
```

//intento enviar el parámetro pero no me funciona

agradezco cualquier ayuda, soy nuevo con React Native

Answer (score 0):

encontré el error.
No es params, es initialParams:

```js
initialParams={{ user: props.name }}
```

Fijate si funciona y avisame!
Referencia: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#updating-params
Saludos.